# What are the benifits to use DevExpress helpers in ASP.NET MVC as compared to general helpers of ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, I heard about the 3rd party of DevExpress for MVC.

I use both general helpers (for example `@Html.TextBox("Name")`) and DevExpress helpers like:

```
@Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
            settings => {
                settings.Name = "textBox2";
                settings.Width = 170;
                settings.Properties.NullText = "Enter your name...";
            }
        ).GetHtml()
```

in basic level applications. But both are working in a similar way.

I'm unable to understand the benefits of using DevExpress helpers in ASP.NET MVC ...

Thanks

Comment: show us which general helper you use for displaying html editors or grids.. or charts

Answer (score 0):

> I'm unable to understand the benefits of using DevExpress helpers in ASP.NET MVC ...

You can [try to compare the capabilities](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDataEditorsDemos/) before and decide after.
Regarding the simplest case (TextBox extension) - take a look at the [TextBox Main Features](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument12045) documentation. The benefits are: display formatting, mask-input, built-in validation, themes... To discover these features in action, please take look at the corresponding [demo](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDataEditorsDemos/Editors/TextBox).